# List all issues updated on specific date, but containing issues which were re-updated later

Tags: youtrack

Take an example. I create an issue on Monday, someone works on in on Wednesday and Thursday. Then on Friday I want to filter all issues, which were updated on Wednesday.

Filter `updated: {appropriate date}` does not help, because it seems like that after the issue was re-updated later it forgets about former updates.

How do I write such query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

Comment: What can I do.. Thank you anyway.